# Are images supported in bots on Skype for Business?

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/Skype-For-Business-Bot-Framework/docs/overview#feature-support), you can send HTML to a Microsoft Bot Framework bot on Skype for Business:

> Your bot can send plain text, HTML, and emoticons to a user or group.

Does that include IMG tags? Can a bot send an image to a user in Skype for Business, and will it render?

Comment: what does MBF stands for?

Comment: Microsoft Bot Framework?

Comment: Are [rich cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-rich-cards) or [adaptive cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/) not an option for you?

Comment: @JasonSowers rich cards and adaptive cards are not currently supported in Skype for Business.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? Did it not work?